# Utilize the ASP.NET Default Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-membership

I am working on a system where authentication / authorization is part of the requirements. My ERD for the system is as follows:

[image]

I haven't fully populated the Entities, but you can probably guess the majority of the fields that will go there, especially for the User entity.

**I do not want to implement my own Membership handling mechanisms**, instead I want my Users table to become (substituted for) the default Users table in the default ASP.NET membership. This way I can go ahead and use all the membership features with little effort (I hope).

I am working in Entity Framework Code First, and would love some help on how exactly I can achieve this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a **Customer table** and **Vote table** like the following. (*Please rename customer table something that makes sense for your project)*.

**Customer table** and **Vote table** basically use **UserId** as *Primary Key* which is also a *Foreign Key* of Users table.

[image]

***Note***: Do not add any extra columns to Users and Memberships tables. If you do so, you cannot use the Default provider; instead, you will need to implement your own membership provider.

***P.S.*** New [Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) use Entity Framework Code First.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening [this](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) article does a very good job of explaining how you can use the new Simplemembership implementation against Entity Framework Code First

Comment: Does that only work with EF 5? I am using EF 4.1 and that has no Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'use all the membership features' theres a **** next to that.

1. If you want to use your own table, you are implementing a custom membership provider. If you are using the Universal Membership providers which is the default option in MVC3 and Web Forms 4.5 you can't use a custom table name.
2. SimpleMembership behind the scenes uses Entity Framework (actually the Universal providers do as well, thats how we can easiest support all our db engines). However it is just that - simple. It is no frills and is missing a lot of the functionality the Universal Membership providers support.

With SimpleMembership you initialize it using your own table name and simply provide it with a table name, an int column name to hold a userId and a string column to hold the user name. You can store *anything* else you want in that table. It's yours. However - don't expect lost/forgotten password functionality to work out of the box, it won't because this is 'simple' membership which takes a more hands off approach.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks. I don't mind if my membership table names aren't chosen by me. How can I plugin the Universal Membership of MVC and Web Forms into my Domain?